# Converting Floating Point to String

Tags: java, floating-point, converters

I'm pretty new to Java and I am currently working on a project where I need to work with [Floating points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

I am trying to convert the value from 3.5E8 (Double value) to a string value of 350000000. I have looked on the internet but currently I can't find a solution.

Comment: Look at [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Comment: `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(f).toPlainString());` ?

Comment: http://way2java.com/string-and-stringbuffer/data-type-float-to-string-conversion/ + many other conversion/casting examples. Recomend to book

Comment: Although the answers so far will work for 3.5E8, they may not do what you want for some other inputs. You need to consider the range of inputs before selecting a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
new BigDecimal(yourValue).toPlainString();
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try String.format

```
String str = String.format("%.0f",3.5E8);
```

or

```
String str = new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(3.5E8);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class , [toPlainString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString%28%29) method :

> Returns a string representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field.

```
 System.out.println(new BigDecimal(doubleValue).toPlainString());
```